# Copying .sqlite db to documents directory on Phone

Tags: flutter, dart, sqflite

I have a routine that copies a local SQLite database (from the Android Studio Assets folder) to the phone's document directory.

The problem I have is that this code is not very good. Sometimes the database is copied completely, and sometimes it is copied partially, or not at all. Its very buggy and I have no idea on how to improve on it.

Many times I get an error saying that certain tables cannot be found.

Here is the code that Im using:

```
  copyDB() async
  {
   // Construct a file path to copy database to
    Directory documentsDirectory = await      getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = join(documentsDirectory.path,     DBAssistanceClass.databaseName);
print('The DB path is: '+ path);

// Only copy if the database doesn't exist
    if (FileSystemEntity.typeSync(path) == FileSystemEntityType.notFound)
    {
      try
      {
        print('Copying DB...');
        // Load database from asset and copy
        ByteData data = await rootBundle.load(
            join('assets', DBAssistanceClass.databaseName));
        List<int> bytes = data.buffer.asUint8List(data.offsetInBytes, data.lengthInBytes);
        // Save copied asset to documents
        await File(path).writeAsBytes(bytes);

        }
      catch (error)
        {

        print(error);

        }
     }

}
```

This is for flutter, and I cannot find anything at all in dart documentation to assist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if it is important to flush when you write the file. There is an [Opening an asset database](https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/blob/master/sqflite/doc/opening_asset_db.md) document in sqflite with a complete example.